# error : .find(…) is not a function nodejs mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongoose, get

I define a controller which code like bellow :

```
const  paymentModel = require("../../models/University");
class PaymentController {
async getPaymentList(req , res){
   const list = await paymentModel.find() 
   .select("amount  description  payDate payId" ).limit(20);
   res.send(list);
}
```

router like bellow :

```
const router = require ("express").Router();
const controller = require("../http/controller/PaymentController");
router.get('/' ,controller.getPaymentList);
module.exports= router;
```

model :

```
 const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
 const schemaPay = new mongoose.Schema({
 payId  :{type:Number, required: true},
 amount :{type :String , required: true},
 description :{type :String , required:true},
 courseId:[schemaCourse] ,
 studentId:[schemaStudent],
 payDate :String ,
 });
 const paymentModel= mongoose.model('StudentPayments' , schemaPay); 
 module.exports={paymentModel };
```

when I test api with postman I get error :paymentModel.find is not a function
can any one help me where is the problem?

Comment: You're exporting the paymentModel inside an object, so do `const { paymentModel } = require('....')` instead of `const paymentModel = require('...')`

Comment: You have created schemaPay and exporting paymentModel that's why it gives error

Comment: Change your export ```module.exports = mongoose.model('schemaPay', schemaPay);```

Comment: I forget to paste this part of my code :   const paymentModel= mongoose.model('StudentPayments' , schemaPay);

Comment: I have several model so I use {} to export all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your model, you are exporting an object with the key paymentModel in it.

In order to access paymentModel from inside that object, you would have to do one of the following:

```
const  {paymentModel} = require("../../models/University");
```

or

```
const  UniversityModel = require("../../models/University"); //then access paymentModel like UniversityModel.paymentModel
```

You could also just export only one particular model instead if you don't want to have to do this, but you say you have multiple exports so yeah.